# Fastest way to compute matrix multiplied with its transpose (AA^T) in Python

Tags: python, performance, numpy, scipy, matrix-multiplication

What is the fastest way to multiply a matrix with its transpose (AA^T) in Python?

I don't think NumPy/SciPy take into account the symmetries involved when using e.g. `np.dot` or `np.matmul`. The resulting matrix is always symmetric so I can imagine there is a faster solution.

Comment: Just test it. `A=np.random.rand(1000,1000);B=np.random.rand(1000,1000);%timeit np.dot(A,B)->10ms; %timeit np.dot(A,A.T) ->7.5ms;`

Comment: Just use numpy directly: [Previously, gemm BLAS operations were used for all matrix products. Now, if the matrix product is between a matrix and its transpose, it will use syrk BLAS operations for a performance boost. This optimization has been extended to @, numpy.dot, numpy.inner, and numpy.matmul.](https://numpy.org/doc/1.16/release.html)