# BLAS input matrix check

Tags: numpy, lapack, blas

Currently I'm searching for how BLAS library is composed.
As I keep going, I could see few functions that get input matrix of specific form.
For instance, LEVEL 3 BLAS SYMM should get matrix A as a symmetric matrix, and as I get close look at fortran implemenation code, SYMM won't behavior as expected if A is not symmetric.
So, to call SYMM, one should check whether input matrix A is symmetric or not, right?
As I know, numpy calls OpenBLAS internally, which takes me to think there will be some code lines describes how numpy check BLAS function paramters.
Are there any materials that describe these points? or am I getting somethin wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Except for a special `A@A.T` case, `matmul` assumes the most general case. Testing for special cases would take too much time.  And there aren't any documented user parameters.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67701335/fastest-way-to-compute-matrix-multiplied-with-its-transpose-aat-in-python

Comment: I saw github codes for numpy, and I strongly guess numpy does not use functions for special cases (Hermitian, packed...so on). So, hpaulj, thx for the correct notation.

Comment: But, after then, I began to wonder why there is no such logic that checks matrix shape compatibility in numpy. How does numpy (or BLAS) check matrix shaep compatibility, which is mandatory to do right matrix multiplicaiton?

Comment: `matmul` certainly does check shape.

Comment: Oh, I just found **dot_alignment_error** part. Thx @hpaulj